# Where to place *ngIf directive?

Tags: angular, directive, angular-ng-if

Is there any difference between

```
<ng-container *ngIf="flag">
       <child-component></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

or directly

```
<child-component *ngIf="flag"></child-component>
```

And what is the best practice for that?

Comment: If you only have one element inside the ng-container, you shouldn't use ng-container. If you have multiple elements inside the ng-container that you want should hide when `flag` is true, you should use the first alternative.

Comment: If you are using for single component then better not to use ng-container directive as your component will include extra directive. If you have multiple components to handle then to avoid multiple same condition you can use ng-directive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-container` is a directive that is not loaded into the DOM by Angular. It's function is to group together other directives.
In the case of `ngIf` it is used to group together different elements that all depend on the same flag.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="flag">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  ...
</ng-container>
```

If you only have one element there is not much grouping to do and you can place the `*ngIf` directly on the element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, maybe I would like to know is there any difference in generating the DOM between the two approaches